# How to detect if a span is resized?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I am trying to detect if height of `span` with contententeditable is changed. Through google I found below methods, but neither seems to work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(event) {
        console.log("hello");
    });
    window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
        console.log("hello");
    });

});
function resized(event){
    console.log("hello");
}
```

html:

```
<span id="test" contenteditable="true" onresize="resized(event)"></span>
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/go5cm096/14/

is there anything wrong I am doing?

Comment: You could try to use the MutationObserver API, which is designed for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

```js
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
const dims = (context)=>{
  const b = context.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log('width:'+b.width+'; height:'+b.height);
}
const test = document.getElementById('test');
dims(test);
test.oninput = function(){
  dims(this);
}
}); // end load
```

```html
<span id='test' contenteditable='true'>test</span>
```